# How do you create custom zalgo text?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I know what zalgo text is and that there are a few websites that can make it for you. But I'm looking for how I can make it however I want." HͥAͣQͫ" is an example, how can I make it so I  can choose the characters that are ontop of the normal characters myself?

Comment: You can't. See [html - How does Zalgo text work? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work) See

Comment: But how was it done then? HͥAͣQͫ has to be done in some way

Comment: You can only use the characters that are combining diacritical marks. i, a and m are in the list but most of the alphabet is not. See [Combining character - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character#cite_note-2)